# iis7 rewrite rules for shared websites

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have an issue that is causing me much grief.

I have 2 websites setup on the same server (only 1 IP available), that have root domain & also www. & *. defined to send traffic to the same IP address.

Let call them

```
http://siteA.com   DNS settup with siteA.com  www.siteA.com  *.siteA.com
http://siteB.com   DNS settup with siteB.com  www.siteB.com  *.siteB.com
```

siteA needs to be the default website is has a binding as such ie. *:80

```
*:80
siteA.com:80
www.siteA.com:80
```

Binding on siteB website exist for:

```
siteB.com:80
www.siteB.com:80
```

What i need is for anything for *.siteB.com goes to siteB.com and not fall through to the default website. Currently mce.siteB.com will fall back to siteA.com

I have tried many combination but can not work this one out.

Also do i put the URL re-write at the website level or at the IIS root level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out in the end, and was purely from a lack of understanding of the URL Rewrite process.

Ended up being very simple

And added the following to the incoming rules of siteA.com, it was just a case of adjusting the pattern in the conditions field. I was taking the incoming url as a url and not the **{QUERY_STRING}** only.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to siteB.com patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*siteB\.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://siteB.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```